# How to assert that an expression does not compile

Tags: java, junit

I have written a piece of framework that adds the possibility for type-safe invocations of its interface. Now, when writing the JUnit tests, I want to show that specific expressions that earlier led to runtime errors are checked by the compiler now.

```
// this does not compile, because nameProp is of type Property<String>
Integer name = interface.getProperty(nameProp);
```

Probably it'd be best to simply comment that code out and leave it like that. I was just wondering whether it'd be possible with some testing framework to write something like

```
assertCompilationError() {
     Integer name = interface.getProperty(nameProp);
}
```

I explicitly do not want to fiddle around with invocations of javac with a custom classpath myself. If there is the possibility for a general solution that could be extracted to framework code (and donated to JUnit or TestNG) such a solution would be welcome as well.

Comment: But writing a JUnit code itself means following Java standards. So the JUnit classes should compile. Right? SO, probably you'll have to dig into javac invocations as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: Exactly, the class itself should compile. I just want to assert that a specific expression does not compile.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Java Compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html)? Maybe you can use that somehow?

Comment: @sorencito: The class won't compile if it contains a "_specific expression [that] does not compile_"

Comment: @jlordo: You've got it - and that's why I'm asking. I suppose I'll need to put a java file into a resource folder and try to compile it from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time, I found following piece of software:

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home

It looks like it should be possible to do some sort of hack in order compile only the block in question. Right now, my example would not work, anyway, because it yet does not support generics.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run JUnit until it compiles which is too late for this check.

You can't use a library to allow code which doesn't compile, to compile so you can check it doesn't compile.

Comment: As jlordo commented, I could compile the code myself using the compiler API. So at least I'd be able to write Strings with Java code in them and compile them.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be curious if you could achieve this by some java scripting language, I'd check in detail beanshell and groovy, maybe they offer something you can make use of.

Because as far as I understand you can invoke their scripts from your java programs (JUnit test in your case).

The most important questions are however:

- do they support full java syntax / the part you're interested in your scenarios?
- is there a way to propagate current classpath to the executed script?

Comment: +1 The classloader will throw `CompilationError` in such cases. So you only have to make sure that there is one test per class/script you try to invoke via groovy/beanshell in this case and not one per method.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could:

```
public static void assertCompilationError() {
    try {
          Integer name = (Integer)(Object)interface.getProperty(nameProp);
    } catch (Exception e) {
          //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool workaround! And works for the example :-) Unfortunately it does not 100% correctly answer the question, as it is about detecting the compile time error. Moreover, it would not work for typed collections due to type erasure.

Comment: @Sorencito How does that work for your example? The non-generic version of your Property would pass the test too (with a ClassCastException).

Comment: @sorencito, I'm absolutely agree. You could consider this workaround as some kind of joke, because, of course, it could not cover all cases, only that, which you mentioned in your question :)

Comment: @assylias Right. That was what I was also thinking after posting my comment :-) Anyway, kind of funny solution to use a double cast...